# GoogleMaps iOS SDK 1.5 won't load

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

So I've started investigating using GoogleMaps iOS SDK.

I followed the instructions:

- Enabled the Google Maps SDK for iOS in the console
- Setup an API key and added the Bundle ID (I used the demo Project Google Supplies)
- Updated the constant 'kAPIKey'the the key in my Project

I run the app and I get the following

> 2013-11-18 11:24:59.155 SDKDemos[7073:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x8c4b0e0 {data={length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
>
> 2013-11-18 11:24:59.233 SDKDemos[7073:6403] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.5.0.5445
>   ...
>
> 2013-11-18 11:25:11.836 SDKDemos[7073:c07] Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x8c1a9b0 {data={length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
>
> 2013-11-18 11:25:11.836 SDKDemos[7073:c07] Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: com.example.SDKDemos

Here is an image from the API Console to show I have bundleID entered correctly
[image: Console Image]

XCode 5.0
iOS SDK 7.0

So it seems I am missing something fairly fundamental here or there is a time I have to wait until my API key is actually activated

**Update:**
Map is now rendering but the ClientParametersRequest failed errors are still being reported

**Update2 :**
Added Image showing example
[image]

Comment: Can you walk me through the exact steps to reproduce? I downloaded 1.5, opened the SDKDemo project in Xcode, added an API Key, then ran the project as is in the emulator, and it worked as expected. What did you do?

Comment: I did the exact same thing

Comment: I just updated the question with a Screenshot of what I am seeing

Comment: What is your internet connectivity like on your desktop/laptop? A failure mode that could be happening here is that the emulator isn't able to connect with Google servers, and thus can't load map data.

Comment: Connection was fine, We have a project using 1.2 that connects fine the only thing that seemed to be an issue is that the -Objc flag is missing from the Demo project

Comment: @CStreel, I have the same thing: I update my settings in google services, add example bundle id and generate key. and example app doesn't work for me. do you solve it? also, I use google sdk version 1.8.1

Comment: Did you check the flag '-ObjC' is set in Other Linker Flags?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out the Demo Project Supplied by Google didn't follow the proper setup and they skipped step 7

> In the Other Linker Flags section, add -ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please raise this as a [bug on our issue tracker for Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Bug)?