# GoogleMapsiOS SDK1.6 won't load on device

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying out the GoogleMaps iOS SDK 1.6 SDKDemoes, and when it load it on the Simulator iPhone Retina (4-inch) on iOS 7.0.3 everything works fine, but when I run it on my local device the same following message pops up. Any idea what is causing this to happen?

```
>2013-12-15 18:40:54.152 SDKDemos[3038:60b] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts 
remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
UserInfo=0x14dbeb50 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The
request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x14db93f0 "The request timed out."}
```

Similar to the following question: 
[GoogleMaps iOS SDK 1.5 won't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038624/googlemaps-ios-sdk-1-5-wont-load)

Comment: After trying it again a few hours later without changing and code, it magically worked.. perhaps the connectivity of wireless was bad...